# mysql - query for thread list of messages with specific conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three tables: user, request and message. I would like to get something like the thread list that android/ios message app shows when launched.

**User**

```
id  username
1   a
2   b
3   c
```

**Request**

```
id
1
2
3
```

**Message**

```
Id  request_id     sender_id   receiver_id message timestamp
1   1       1       2       asd 2013-06-10 06:45
2   1       1       3       sdf 2013-06-10 06:42
3   2       1       1       dfg 2013-06-10 06:41
4   2       1       2       fgh 2013-06-11 06:40
5   2       1       2       ghj 2013-06-12 07:45
6   2       2       1       jkl 2013-06-10 06:45
7   3       3       1       zxc 2013-06-10 03:45
8   3       3       1       xcv 2013-06-10 05:45
```

What I would like to get is something like this:

**Thread**

```
request_id  sender_name receiver_name   last_message    last_timestamp
1       a       b       asd     2013-06-10 06:45
1       a       c       sdf     2013-06-10 06:42
2       a       b       ghj     2013-06-12 07:45
2       a       a       dfg     2013-06-10 06:41
3       c       a       xcv     2013-06-10 05:45
```

Here, request_id + sender_id + receiver_id is unique for each row and last_message, last_timestamp shows the latest entry from the message table. The order will be last_timestamp descending. How do I get this table?

Comment: You say that "*the order will be `last_timestamp` descending*", but in the given example the message `'ghj'` (sent two days after all the other messages) appears not only in the middle of all the records but furthermore in the middle of all those with the same `request_id` too.  Please clarify the desired sort order of the resultset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html), which can be found by joining the `Messages` table to a subquery that identifies the identifying (maximal) timestamp for each group:

```
SELECT   Message.request_id,
         Sender.username   AS sender_name,
         Receiver.username AS receiver_name,
         Message.message   AS last_message,
         Message.timestamp AS last_timestamp
FROM     Message NATURAL JOIN (
           SELECT   request_id,
                    sender_id,
                    receiver_id,
                    MAX(timestamp) timestamp
           FROM     Message
           GROUP BY request_id, sender_id, receiver_id
         ) t
    JOIN User Sender   ON   Sender.id = Message.sender_id
    JOIN User Receiver ON Receiver.id = Message.receiver_id
ORDER BY Message.request_id, last_timestamp DESC
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bceb/1/0).

Note that the order of my resultset differs from that expected in your question for the reasons highlighted in [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851962/mysql-query-for-thread-list-of-messages-with-specific-conditions#comment27817674_18851962):

> You say that "*the order will be `last_timestamp` descending*", but in the given example the message `'ghj'` (sent two days after all the other messages) appears not only in the middle of all the records but furthermore in the middle of all those with the same `request_id` too.  Please clarify the desired sort order of the resultset?

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm. I didn't know the use of natural join

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake ordering that sample table. But then again, that table was hand made. So mistakes can happen. But you got it right.

Comment: I have another problem. From your [answer](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bceb/1/0) I found duplicate results (3rd and 4th row). In that case sender and receiver id have been interchanged. But I only want one of them (the latest one). How can I do that?

Comment: @AlamKanak: It's a bit messy and won't scale very well, but you can use `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2b51/1/0).  If it all possible, I would be more inclined to add one or two more columns to the table that would enable one to identify a conversation's participants without such additional work.